# BIRT - Java 1.8

Tags: birt

I was using BIRT together with java 1.6 but recently have updated java to the latest version which is a prerequistie for other applications. Since then BIRT is not working.
I was using BIRT 4.4.0.v201405191524.
Is there any possibilty to work BIRT with the java 1.8 version?

Comment: You should mention what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 1):

BIRT has some dependencies which are given [here](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/).
They have specifically mentioned only *Java 1.6 JDK/JRE* as a pre-requisite but *not higher version of JDK/JRE*.
The BIRT engine 4.5 itself is still compiled with a java 6 compliance but many eclipse libraries require java 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using BIRT 4.3.2 v20140211-1400 with java 1.8.
I'm using jre 1.8.20 and  compiler version 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

We recently upgraded our Dev environments to use BIRT 4.6.0 v20160607-2122 with Java 8_121, using Eclipse Neon 4.6.2

All is well, BIRT works great, with one minor issue: on the Edit Chart dialog's Select Data tab, the Summation button for the Value Series / Slice Size Definition is always disabled.